# Is it correct to say that rail stayed unchanged?

Tags: word-in-context

I asked the writer if it's correct to say that rail stayed unchanged since rail can't stay unchanged and only rail shipments can stay unchanged. He told me that "rail" is enough. Readers would understand "rail" to mean "the quantity of goods shipped by rail." Is it true that I don't need to say "rail shipments" and "rail" is enough?

> Shipments increased for all modes except **rail**, which stayed
> essentially unchanged.

[image]

Comment: What is the source? Who is the writer? What is your job?

Comment: The chart is a writing task of a language test. The writer is my teacher who is a native English speaker.

Comment: Any particular reason to doubt them? I mean they are experts at the writing task for your test and know your level well.  I don't.

Comment: Because you said some native speakers have opinions about grammar and rhetoric that are wrong. In another question, you disagreed with my teacher about the use of "in addition". Anyway, I've developed a mindset of not listening to only one person.

Comment: Okay, but if we disagree, please don't say you are "confused".  Do you know the proverb,  "A person with a clock knows the time, a person with two clocks is never sure."?

Comment: By itself "rail increased" or "rail stayed unchanged" isn't useful, but you can use context to work out what it means. Certainly there is nothing ungrammatical about it, although people have all kinds of opinions about what is good style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context (referring to the graph, in a paragraph discussing the amount of goods shipped by various modes) using "rail" to mean "the amount of goods shipped by rail" seems clear enough to me.  This is synecdoche, and is a reasonably well know figure of speech, and non-literal use of language.

By itself "rail increased" or "rail stayed unchanged" isn't useful, but you can use context to work out what it means. Certainly, there is nothing ungrammatical about it, although people have all kinds of opinions about what is good style. (Stuart F)

Comment: @StuartF  I've adopted your comment for my answer.